# Update stored content everyday with Service(AlarmManager) or launch period deduction

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager, ormlite, auto-update

I have List of contacts, which I can save on some period. And I should to update the terms of saving everyday. Simply, minus one day to terms of all contacts everyday.

I see two possible solutions :

1) Service, which will use AlarmManager and update content at specified time everyday.

2) Rememeber the last launch of the application, check the difference and deduct this difference from stored terms..

Second approach seems to me more perfomance efficient. Can somebody advise something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue.

I use method, which is called in onCreate() method in class, which extends from Application class:

```
private void setRecurringAlarm(Context context) {
               Intent intent = new Intent(AlarmReceiver.ACTION_ALARM);
                  AlarmManager alarms = (AlarmManager) this
                         .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
               final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,
                 1234567, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

               alarms.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                 System.currentTimeMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pIntent);

              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

My AlarmReceiver class:

```
  public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "AlarmReceiver";
    public static String ACTION_ALARM = "com.alarammanager.alaram";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Intent downloader = new Intent(context, UpdateService.class);
        downloader.setAction(Constants.UPDATE_SERVICE);
        context.startService(downloader);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Entered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

and my Service, where desired operation is executed:

```
      public class UpdateService extends IntentService {

        Boolean isRunning = false;
        private ContentRepository _contentRepo;
        public UpdateService() {
            super("UpdateService");
        }
        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            faq = new FrequentlyUsedMethods(this);
            _contentRepo = new ContentRepository(this.getContentResolver(), this);
            this.context = this;
            if (!isRunning)
                archiveDaysDeduct();

            return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
        }

    private void archiveDaysDeduct() 
        {
            isRunning = true;
            Log.i("updateService", "archiveDaysDeduct");
            ArrayList<ContactItem> contacts = faq.getDisplayContacts(this);
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "update service and I'm here", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context.getApplicationContext());
            Dao<ContactItem,Integer> daoContact = null;

            String yourDate = faq.getCurrentDate();
            if (SharedPrefs.getInstance().getSharedPrefs()!=null)

                if (!SharedPrefs.getInstance().getSharedPrefs().getString(Constants.CURRENT_DATE, "").equalsIgnoreCase(yourDate))
                {       
SharedPrefs.getInstance().getSharedPrefs().edit().putString(Constants.CURRENT_DATE, yourDate);

                     try {
                         daoContact = db.getContactDao();
                     }
                     catch(Exception e)
                     {
                         e.printStackTrace();
                     }
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "I'm going to decrement the save dates", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    UpdateBuilder<ContactItem, Integer> updateBuilder = daoContact.updateBuilder();
                     DeleteBuilder<ContactItem, Integer> daoContactDelete = daoContact.deleteBuilder();
                     Log.i("contacts size in update service", Integer.toString(contacts.size()));
                    for (ContactItem a : contacts)
                    {
                        if (a.getDays()==0)
                        {
                            try {

                                daoContactDelete.where().eq("id", a.getId());
                                daoContact.delete(daoContactDelete.prepare());

                            } 
                            catch (SQLException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            try {
                                Log.i("contacts to update days", a.toString());
                                a.setDays(a.getDays()-1);
                                daoContact.update(a);
                            } catch (SQLException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    stopSelf();

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to run your service once a day with an AlamManager it will more then performance/battery efficient.

You can increase the performance further if the service doesn't have to be run at the exact moment every day by using `RTC` instead of `RTC_WAKEUP`.

This way you app wont wake up the CPU, rather the task will be executed when the user uses the phone again.(if the alarm is late already).  But still you don't have to worry so much if the service isn't being run multiple times a day..think of it as an alarm clock that wakes you up everyday by ringing, doesn't eat up your battery.

Comment: as I understand, when I start Service, my application will be running. Even if it killed, right?

Comment: Yes your app will be running, since Services are part of your app. But the user wont have a clue that its running unless you inform him in some way or start an activity from the service.

Comment: What do you mean by killed? If for example you start your Service from an activity, and the user shuts down the activity the service will still continue running until it finishes its task if you configured it that way with flags START_STICKY or NOT_STICKY etc...but in extreme cases android can shutdown your service if there is a serious memory/resource overload and your apps is scheduled for shutdown, but in your case you should worry about that at all.